What is the purpose of these 33-ohm series resistors on the RMII side of the LAN8742A?
Currently in the process of trying to figure out how to use this chip (LAN8742A-CZ-TR) in my own design and I'm looking at a few schematics using the chip as a reference. Both schematics make use of these resistors, however I can't find any mention of them in the datasheet and neither seem to be consistent in their use. Any ideas would be appreciated.



The 33 ohm series resistors are typically used on high-speed lines as a “series source termination” when the attached trace acts as a transmission line.
The 33 ohms value is used to match a typical CMOS chip's internal low-impedance (~10 or 20 ohms) driver to a PCB trace designed as a 50 ohms transmission line, when there is a high-impedance at the receiver end (i.e., deliberately has no end termination on the transmission line).
The overall effect is that a half-voltage wave front propagates down the transmission line, then doubles at the receiver end (due to “high impedance” boundary) to reach the full switching voltage at the receiver.  The returned (positive half voltage) reflection is then absorbed back at the source side again by the sum of 33 ohms + 20-ish ohms internal driver impedance.
This technique is also called “reflected wave switching”.  For edge-sensitive signals like a clock, this technique can only be used for single-source to single-receiver (point-to-point) topologies, but the technique can also be used for multiple receiver busses with appropriate synchronization between source and sampling timing at the receiver.
When used, the series source termination resistor needs to be placed adjacent (close to) to the ASIC pin on the source side (transmitting side) of the trace, as the resistor must form lumped impedance with the ASIC's internal driver to be effective. This termination scheme works best on uni-directional point-to-point signals, but is typically not needed if the ASIC driver has adjustable impedance settings or is already tuned to have an internal 50 ohms source impedance.
Transmission line effects are very dependent on the overall length (source to receiver) of the PCB trace compared to the edge rate (rise/fall time) of the signal.  So providing a transmission line termination (series source or other termination types like end termination) becomes helpful (often necessary) when the two chips being connected are separated further apart or the signal edges are very fast.

Except that source termination resistors do nothing if they are placed at the receive end of the transmission line, as is R24 and R25 on the bottom schematic.

@SteveSh the chip supports Auto-MDIX, the "RX" pins can also become the transmit end, depending on circumstances. See table 2-4 on page 11 and section 3.3 on pg 24 of the datasheet.

Thanks for that.  I was just going by the pin names on the schematic.

@mbrig FIGURE 1-2: ARCHITECTURAL OVERVIEW in the LAN8742A datasheet shows that Auto-MDIX happens on the analogue TXP/TXN and RXP/RXN pins, rather than the digital TXD[0:1] and RXD[0:1] pins. Where the TXD[0:1] and RXD[0:1] pins don't change direction. The series termination resistors are shown in the traces for the TXD[0:1] and RXD[0:1] pins. Albeit in the schematic there is no note about which device the series termination resistors are placed at on the PCB layout.

@ChesterGillon you're right! In which case, the RXD pins are actually the ones which "transmit" (from the chip's perspective).... which I'm sure has never confused anyone!

The answer already mentions the resistors are for series termination.
The Schematic Checklist for the LAN8742, 24-pin QFN Package found on the Microchip site does contain some mention of series termination:

In the RMII Interface section:

Provisions should be made for series terminations for all outputs on the RMII Interface. Series resistors will enable the designer to closely match the output driver impedance of the LAN8742 and PCB trace impedance to minimize ringing on these signals. Exact resistor values are application dependant and must be analyzed in-system. A suggested starting point for the value of these series resistors is 10.0 Ω.


In the Crystal Connections section:

It is recommended that the designer use a series 33 Ω termination resistor on the REFCLKO pin. The value can then be adjusted to compensate for any PCB trace impedance inconsistencies.



While the suggested series termination of 10 Ω for the RMII interface differs from the 33 Ω value in the circuit in the question, the referenced schematic checklist does qualify that the exact resistor values are application dependent.
A missing, or incorrect value, for series termination can cause ringing at the receiver. This can be particularly problematic for clocks where ringing may cause the receiver to be "double clocked" from what should be a single clock transition. In the past remember debugging designs where on probing signals at a receiver found a poor integrity signal with ringing, and modified the design to add a series resistor at the source.
I'm not sure if modern PCB design tools can take models of device pin characteristics and the impedance of the PCB traces, and be able to recommend series termination resistor values by analysis.

They are used to remove reflections in the signal. Not always necessary, but a good idea and the 33 ohm in your case could also be changed if you run into some signal issues as this is just a good stating point.
The RMII lines are usually recommended to be 50 ohms, but the transmitter or receiver usually don’t have 50 ohms terminations. Then you can get reflections. That is why when you have a low impedance source you add something slightly lower than 50ohm and you have a line that is matched. You should notice that these resistors are always placed closed to the source.

Those are series resistors, they help limit the current and the rise times between the PHY and the RMII controller.
